# Cleaning a NSString ranges

Tags: nsstring

I'm trying to clean a text string. For exemple:

```
[bla bla bla f&oacute;rmula MELD" width="990" height="718" bla bla bla bla]
```

I want to remove `width="990" height="718"` in my whole text. I want to locate every `width="xxx" height="xxx"` and remove them. In some cases they are inverted `height="xxx" width="xxx"`

The numbers in `width="990" height="718"` are not the same every time.

Comment: Scan for "width=" and "height=" and then take it from there.  Try something.

Comment: Thanks.
I can scan for "width" and remplace it for "" but the problem are the numbers between quotation marks. I'm trying to detect the first quotation mark after the position of width but I can't for now.

Comment: You can scan for `width="`, then scan off characters until you see a second `"`.